# f:ajax not re rendering target DOM element (JBoss error?)

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, seam2

I am running JBoss 7.1.0.Final with the default JSF 2.1 .

I have been having problems getting the render attribute of a f:ajax to work

Here is my code

```
    <h:form> 
       <h:panelGrid> 
          <h:inputText value="#{bean.text}" > 
             <f:ajax event="keyup" render="text"/> 
          </h:inputText> 
          <h:outputText id="text" value="#{bean.text}" /> 
       </h:panelGrid> 
    </h:form>
```

With a bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean") 
public class Bean 
{ 
      private String text; 

public String getText()
{
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text)
{
    this.text = text;
}
 }
```

The page renders but the value entered in the inputtext does not render as outputtext.

There does seem to be some interaction with the server as I get

JBAS010152: APPLICATION ERROR: transaction still active in request with status 0

happening on each keyup event?

Note that I am running this within Seam 2.3

Comment: try to add some scope annotation to the bean , like `@SessionScoped`